# How to create multiple POST methods on an Azure Mobile Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I have an Azure Mobile Service with multiple controllers. One of my controllers (TestSetController) has some extra methods to check on insert.

Problem I need to solve: The TestSet table has two different types of TestSets, one for a local team and another for a field team. The table contains data for both and the records are differentiated by a "TeamType" field which says if the local team inserted the TestSet or the field team did. On any insert I want to check if a similar TestSet exists that was inserted by the other team. I want to compare the TestSets (if found) then do some other inserts/updates on the same table if the TestSets are different.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
PostTestSetDTO on type sbp_ctService.Controllers.TestSetController
CheckForDiscrepancy on type sbp_ctService.Controllers.TestSetController
CompareTestPointAttempts on type sbp_ctService.Controllers.TestSetController
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.ActionSelectorCacheItem.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ApiController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext(), Id=f07761ae-1be7-4f00-90b0-685dd0c108f3, Category='App.Request'
```

Here's my controller:

```
    public class TestSetController : TableController<TestSetDTO>
    {
        private Context context;

        protected override void Initialize(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
        {
            base.Initialize(controllerContext);
            context = new Context();
            DomainManager = new SimpleMappedEntityDomainManager<TestSetDTO, TestSet>(context, Request, Services, testset => testset.Id);
        }

        // GET tables/TestSet
        [QueryableExpand("TestPointAttempts")]
        public IQueryable<TestSetDTO> GetAllTestSetDTO()
        {
            return Query(); 
        }

        // GET tables/TestSet/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public SingleResult<TestSetDTO> GetTestSetDTO(string id)
        {
            return Lookup(id);
        }

        // PATCH tables/TestSet/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task<TestSetDTO> PatchTestSetDTO(string id, Delta<TestSetDTO> patch)
        {
             return UpdateAsync(id, patch);
        }

        // POST tables/TestSet/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostTestSetDTO(TestSetDTO item)
        {
            TestSet testSet = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<TestSetDTO, TestSet>(item);
            this.CheckForDiscrepancy(testSet);

            TestSetDTO current = await InsertAsync(item);
            return CreatedAtRoute("Tables", new { id = current.Id }, current);
        }

        // DELETE tables/TestSet/48D68C86-6EA6-4C25-AA33-223FC9A27959
        public Task DeleteTestSetDTO(string id)
        {
             return DeleteAsync(id);
        }

        public TestSet CheckForDiscrepancy(TestSet sourceTestSet)
        {

            // Set the team type to search for opposite to the one being posted.
            string searchTeamType = null;
            if (sourceTestSet.TestTeamType == "D")
            {
                searchTeamType = "F";
            }
            if (sourceTestSet.TestTeamType == "F")
            {
                searchTeamType = "D";
            }

            var testSetTable = context.TestSets;

            TestSet foundTestSet = (from ts in testSetTable
                                    where ts.TileId == sourceTestSet.TileId && ts.ScenarioId == sourceTestSet.ScenarioId && ts.TestTeamType.StartsWith(searchTeamType)
                                    select ts).SingleOrDefault();

            // If no other test set was found from the opposing team then the test set is missing.
            // Else a testSet was found so continue with checks.
            if (foundTestSet == null)
            {
                sourceTestSet.DiscrepancyTypeId = DiscrepancyType.Missing.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                var testPointAttemptTable = context.TestPointAttempts;

                // Get all of the associated TestPointAttempts for each testSet.
                sourceTestSet.TestPointAttempts = (from tpa in testPointAttemptTable
                                                   where tpa.TestSetId == sourceTestSet.Id
                                                   orderby tpa.TestAttemptNumber
                                                   select tpa).ToList<TestPointAttempt>();

                foundTestSet.TestPointAttempts = (from tpa in testPointAttemptTable
                                                  where tpa.TestSetId == foundTestSet.Id
                                                  orderby tpa.TestAttemptNumber
                                                  select tpa).ToList<TestPointAttempt>();

                bool matchingTestSets = CompareTestPointAttempts(sourceTestSet.TestPointAttempts, foundTestSet.TestPointAttempts);

                if (!matchingTestSets)
                {
                    sourceTestSet.DiscrepancyTypeId = DiscrepancyType.Discrepancy.ToString();
                    sourceTestSet.DiscrepancyTestSetId = foundTestSet.Id;
                }

            }

            return sourceTestSet;
        }

        public bool CompareTestPointAttempts(IEnumerable<TestPointAttempt> sourceTPAs, IEnumerable<TestPointAttempt> foundTPAs)
        {
            bool pass = false;

            // First check if the total number of testPointAttempts are the same
            if (sourceTPAs.Count() == foundTPAs.Count())
            {
                foreach (TestPointAttempt sTpa in sourceTPAs)
                {
                    bool foundMatch = false;

                    foreach (TestPointAttempt fTpa in foundTPAs)
                    {
                        if (sTpa.TestAttemptNumber == fTpa.TestAttemptNumber)
                        {
                            if (sTpa.TalkIn == fTpa.TalkIn && sTpa.TalkOut == fTpa.TalkOut)
                            {
                                foundMatch = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!foundMatch)
                    {
                        return pass;
                    }
                }

                // The foreach loop finished successfully meaning all matches were found
                pass = true;
            }

            return pass;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The type of discrepancy a TestSet can have.
        /// </summary>
        public enum DiscrepancyType
        {
            Discrepancy,
            Missing,
            None
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) to map between the entity models. Any help would be appreciated. I've looked at some different answers on StackOverflow for ASP.NET but they all talk about updating the config.Routes. This is for an Azure Mobile Service which might have different requirements than a simple ASP.NET website though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as making the two methods private and leaving the actual POST method as public. ASP.NET will only make routes automatically for public methods.